# Change size of window depending on size of the screen,Java

Tags: java, resize, window, frame, screen-size

I want to ask something because I have no idea.I have made a program on Java(Netbeans) and I want to check the size of windows.I want to change depending on the size of screen.Have you any idea?Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example..

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
```

Comment: Can you ask something? It works when I call a new Frame.But how can I use it for the first Frame (main) ?

Comment: private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        dispose();
        Frame1 f = new Frame1(spd);
        f.setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        f.setVisible(true);
    }                            I use this code when I want to call a new Frame and as you said,the window has the size of my screen as I want.But I don't know where I have to put frame.SetSize(...) in my main Frame.

Comment: **public class ScreenSaver extends JFrame {
 public ScreenSaver() {
   setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
   setVisible(true);
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  new ScreenSaver();
 }
}** this is you asked..??

Answer (score 0):

To get the screen size:

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
double width = screenSize.getWidth();
double height = screenSize.getHeight();
```

Then, using `width` and `height`, set the size of the frame

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of the frame API:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame(...);
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```